# Headers with video in background and image overlay

Tags: video-header

How can I code/set up a  header where, instead of having a video on auto play, it's in the background for users to play when they click the play icon.

[image: See screenshot] or go to startwithwhy.com

Answer (score 0):

So, you want auto play or not?
I think in any case these it might be useful: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd